# NoSuchMethodError when initializing the MongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, morphia

I shade `Morphia` in my `pom.xml`, using the versions shown for `Mongo` and `Morphia`. I have to use an older version because I'm working with `Java 8` and the `UUID` converter only works in this version of `Morphia`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.morphia.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

When attempting to create the datastore at runtime, the following line of Java code:

```java
private static final Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "vulcandev");
```

Throws a `NoSuchMethodError`:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.(Lcom/mongodb/internal/connection/Cluster;Lorg/bson/codecs/configuration/CodecRegistry;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/mongodb/client/internal/Crypt;)V

With the full stack trace:

> [22:56:37 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling VulcanCore
> v3.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>
> > com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.(Lcom/mongodb/internal/connection/Cluster;Lorg/bson/codecs/configuration/CodecRegistry;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/mongodb/client/internal/Crypt;)V at
> >
> > > com.mongodb.MongoClient.(MongoClient.java:346) ~[?:?]
> > > at com.mongodb.MongoClient.(MongoClient.java:205) ~[?:?]
> > > at com.mongodb.MongoClient.(MongoClient.java:194) ~[?:?]
> > > at com.mongodb.MongoClient.(MongoClient.java:155) ~[?:?]
> > > at vulcanprisons.iron.vulcancore.mongo.MongoManager.(MongoManager.java:13) ~[?:?]
> > > at vulcanprisons.iron.vulcancore.players.PlayerDataManager.setup(PlayerDataManager.java:13) ~[?:?]
> > > at vulcanprisons.iron.vulcancore.VulcanCore.setupManagers(VulcanCore.java:40) ~[?:?]
> > > at vulcanprisons.iron.vulcancore.VulcanCore.onEnable(VulcanCore.java:33) ~[?:?]